# JSoup throwing an error when using the Connect function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup, okhttp

So I am trying to parse a website using JSoup, however when I try to get a hold of the document using this function right here

`Document mBlogDocument = Jsoup.connect("https://google.com").get();`
It throws this in the StackTrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fireflydevelopments.themerchant, PID: 18184
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1523)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)

//This is the line that throws the error, the one I referred to above
        at com.uhuh.theh.Item.doInBackground(Item.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6653)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6625)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26223)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7470)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

And I can't for the life of me figure out where it goes wrong I have OkHttp installed as well.

Comment: this has nothing to do with jsoup. you are making a request on main thread. do the connection in a thread or asynctask

Comment: Ah! Thank you! :-)